# How to modify the behaviour of a method inside a class file

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft

I am attempting to modify the behavior of GUI Drawing inside the popular game 'Minecraft'.

Currently I'm left with two options, rewrite every single GUI in the game or rewrite their superclass. So I'm going to go with the assumption that using reflection and modifying the superclass is going to be a lot easier.

I have this method, which handles drawing buttons and labels to the screen in the compiled GuiScreen.class

```
public void drawScreen(int p_73863_1_, int p_73863_2_, float p_73863_3_)
{
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < this.buttonList.size(); ++k)
    {
        ((GuiButton)this.buttonList.get(k)).drawButton(this.mc, p_73863_1_, p_73863_2_);
    }

    for (k = 0; k < this.labelList.size(); ++k)
    {
        ((GuiLabel)this.labelList.get(k)).func_146159_a(this.mc, p_73863_1_, p_73863_2_);
    }
}
```

I would like to simply add a line in each of the for loops which does

```
System.out.println("This for loop just run!")
```

Only for the time being, once I have that down I'm sure I can figure out the rest.

I'm already aware of how to use reflection to access private methods and modify non-static/private fields. How would I go about using reflection to either modify or replace a method, in comparison to simply invoking it.

Comment: I don't think reflection is the way to go. You might want to check out bcel https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use some variant of [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), a paradigm that lets you change code behavior without modifying the original code (I think -- I'm no expert in this).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard My apologies for not knowing the correct wording for this, but are you talking about using ASM/Bytecode?

Comment: @Storm- You said you want to change the behaviour from the class file which is what bcel allow you to do.. Or perhaps I misundersood your question ?

Comment: I learned programming using bcel few years ago when I was trying to hack a game I was playing ;)

Comment: I would like to modify the behaviour of this particular method inside a class file. I already have access to the methods however, I can extend upon this class and use it however I want... I just can't modify it.

Comment: that is not how it works, you extend classes and override their behaviors, you do not try and manipulate the existing binaries.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm trying to modify the behaviors of other classes which I can't access by modifying the class they extend which I've managed to do using bytecode manipulation.